# How I can delete a custom evt file?

Tags: c#, events

I am implementing an application that reads a custom event files (.evt) with the  `EventLogQuery` and `EventLogReader` classes and writes these events in a plain text file. I am interested in deleting the EVT file each time the file is processed or deleting all the files when the program finishes.

I simply tried the `Delete()` method of the `File` class but this doesn't work and the program throws an exception in this method:

> 'The file is being used by another program'.

I don't have access to the code at the moment but I want know if exist any specific method to delete the event log files. I found `EventLog.Delete()` method but im not sure if you can specify the evt file and not the name of the default name log (Security, Application, System, etc).

P.D: The evt files don't are evt files of the System in which are being executed the program. These files are exported evt files of another computer.

Comment: Does the file have the read-only flag? How do you stop processing the file? Are you sure you have closed the file in your code? Make sure you dispose all `EventLogReader` instances (put inside a `using` clause or call `Dispose()`)

Comment: I don't know if the file has the read-only flag. I have to see it. I think that the problem is I don't close the file processed because I didn't know how to close the reading of an event file. I will try with the clause using or with the method Dispose(). Tomorrow I will probe it and notify you if works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The exception don't appear more, I have used Method Dispose(). Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I have made this an answer so that you can accept it (click the checkmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you have closed the file before deleting it. `EventLogReader` is disposable, so make sure you have put it into a `using` clause or that your code calls `Dispose()`.